# What does "roaming" mean, technically?

Tags: c#

I came across the "roaming user.config" when I was making a small .NET WinForm app. I know the literal meaning of the word "roaming", but what is the technical definition of "roaming". Could some one give me a scenario explanation? Many thanks!   8^D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is referring to Windows' [Roaming Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_Profile) feature.

Answer (score 3):

Windows roaming: re-mapping directories over the network so that the user sees their "home computer" settings, even when using a different computer.

My thought is that .net is trying to aid you in placing the config file on the dir system so that your app will work correctly in the roaming scenario.

Added: For example, placing the config file in C:\ (root dir of C:) is not a good idea since it won't "roam". Putting the config file in %USERPROFILE% directory is a good idea since the roaming machinery will ensure that the file will be available while roaming.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a Domain and I log in with my Account on multiple PCs, Roaming settings go with me, while local settings don't. That is why stuff like Resolution, File Paths etc. should be Local (as different PCs might have different hardware) and stuff that is non-PC specific should be roaming.